# Android AVD Gmail app: issues with connecting to google servers upon selecting the Gmail app

Tags: android, email, gmail, android-virtual-device, connectivity

I have an android app, where there is a certain activity through which the users can send an email to a preset email address. There is a "send email" button in the activity, and if the user clicks the button, it will prompt the user to choose an email server of their choice to send the email. To achieve this, I have used Intent based on the examples for using Email Intent in this link: [Common Intents in Android](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common).

Everything works fine, whenever I click on the button, it prompts the user to select a mail app. If the user chooses the gmail app, it asks to setup an email address. Clicking on it, it gets to another screen with a list containing google and other email clients. If I click and select google, it waits for some time, then displays this message:

> Couldn't sign in: There was a problem communicating with Google servers. Try again later.

What is the possible reason behind this issue? I am running the app from an Android Virtual Device, and in my case it's Nexus 5 , API 25.

**UPDATE:**
This is definitely not an issue with my code, as I have tested the app in a real device instead of an avd and it worked fine. Hence I am removing all my code from the post. It seems to be an issue with setting up the emulator's gmail app, but I am unable to pinpoint the reason.

For better understanding, I am posting the screenshots of the problem I am going through:

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

[image: Screenshot 3]

[image: Screenshot 4]

Comment: did you check if user is already logged in the gmail app ?

Comment: @mdeora No the user is not logged in the gmail app. Basically, the user is myself, and I am testing the app from the AVD, not from a real device. In the AVD, whenever gmail app comes, it asks me to setup my email address. That's where I get stuck.

Comment: But I guess that’s the intended behaviour. What’s the problem in it?

Comment: @mdeora That's alright in itself, only that while trying to connect to the google servers to set up my gmail address, it shows that it's loading for a couple of minutes, and then all on a sudden it stops loading and throws that message.

Comment: Please check the updates in my post. Thank you.

Comment: I don't know is that still relevant, but it helped me some time ago: `Options->System->Advanced->Reset options->Reset app preferences`